# Postgresql. Ошибка "Select into" внутри процедуры

Tags: postgresql

Необходимо реализовать конструкцию select into внутри процедуры postgre

Вот обычный запрос - все ок

```
 select 1 into "public"."t1"
```

Этот же запрос при создании процедуры

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "public"."testProc1"()
 LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $$ 
 BEGIN
 select 1
 into "public"."t1"
 END; 
$$
```

```
ERROR:  "public.t1" is not a known variable
LINE 5:  into "public"."t1"
              ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 89
```

С чем это связано и как можно победить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html

> ### Notes
>
> CREATE TABLE AS is functionally similar to SELECT INTO. CREATE TABLE AS is the recommended syntax, since **this form of SELECT INTO is not available in ECPG or PL/pgSQL, because they interpret the INTO clause differently**. Furthermore, CREATE TABLE AS offers a superset of the functionality provided by SELECT INTO.